# Ajax - Function to check if Url exists

Tags: javascript, ajax, readystate

I'm building a building a website using the Reddit API to display images from Reddit. 
I'm getting the data via JSON then use it to build the page, using URLs provided as sources for the images.

Some of the URLs that I get don't go to images directly, but instead to image hosting sites (like imgur.com). Usually, adding '.jpg' at the end of the URL takes me to the right image.

So, doing that, I would like to check if the URL + '.jpg' exists before using it.

I tried to build a function to check the url.

```
function checkUrl(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState==4){
            console.log(request.readyState);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};

//Then I use the function to check and append the data to the page
var url = url+'.jpg';
if(checkUrl(url)){
    //work with the data
}else{
    //do nothing
}
```

Nothing happens to the page, still I get the readyState logged into the console, so the checkUrl() function seems to be returning true.

What I am doing wrong ? I am pretty new to the whole Ajax thing, so some help would very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that when `request.readyState == 4` this means the request has completed, *regardless* of what the result of that request was.  So even if the URL you request returns a "404 not found", you'll still see the XHR resolving itself to readyState 4.

To address what you're trying to do, I'd recommend checking the status code of the response.  For example, using your code:

```
if(request.status==200){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, but whenever I use request.status, it breaks the whole javascript, and i get this error in the console : Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Comment: Edit : That's only in Chrome. The code is still working in Firefox, but it's not appending the data.

Comment: After I wrote this, I also realized what others have said in this thread... due to your AJAX requests asynchronous nature, checkurl will never actually return a true/false value.  What you want to do is perform the logic in a "success" case in the if(status==200) statement and the error case in the else.

Answer (score 3):

**Why your code won't work:**

Your AJAX request is asynchronous, and `if(checkUrl(url)){` will return null (false) as the function `checkUrl()` sends the AJAX request and **immediately returns**, before the AJAX call has completed.

Change

```
request.open('GET', url, true);
```

to

```
request.open('GET', url, false);
```

**Also**, move your `request.send()` to after the `request.onreadystatechange()` as now it is a non-async request.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState==4){
        console.log(request.readyState);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
request.send();
```

**Or**, you could simply place your check logic into the onreadystatechange function:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){

    var url = url+'.jpg';
    if(request.readyState==4){
        //work with the data
    }else{
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is misunderstanding of AJAX; AJAX is basically asynchronous, and that's why the behavior you are describing.
I've used the following to get a simple true/false indication whether a URL is valid, in a synchronous manner:

```
function isValidURL(url) {
    var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(url);
    var isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodedURL + "%22&format=json",
      type: "get",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        isValid = data.query.results != null;
      },
      error: function(){
        isValid = false;
      }
    });

    return isValid;
}
```

The usage is then trivial:

```
var isValid = isValidURL("http://www.wix.com");
alert(isValid ? "Valid URL!!!" : "Damn...");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you need to use `type: "head"` instead of `type: "get"`. GET returns everything where HEAD just returns the headers, which is all you actually need to test a URL.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` value of `request.reonreadystatechange` is not the `return` value of checkUrl. Try this:

```
function checkUrl(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState==4){
            console.log(request.readyState);
            // perform your data manipulation here
            // don't separate it with the request
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

On Safari, `ActiveXObject` will work fine, compared to `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function isThere(url)
{
    var req= new AJ(); // XMLHttpRequest object
    try {
        req.open("HEAD", url, false);
        req.send(null);
        //alert(req.status); //un-comment if need alert for status code

        return req.status== 200 ? true : false;
    }
    catch (er) {
        //alert ('ERROR:'); // un-comment if need alert for error
        return false;
    }
}

function AJAX()
{
    var obj;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) obj= new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            obj= new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        }
        catch(er)
        {
            try
            {
                obj= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(er)
            {
                obj= false;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```